# How to configure PostgreSQL password? on a new VM

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

I installed my postgresql like this.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

and accessed it like this

```
sudo -i -u postgres
```

and my a gist of my pga_hba.conf

```
# DO NOT DISABLE!
# If you change this first entry you will need to make sure that the
# database superuser can access the database using some other method.
# Noninteractive access to all databases is required during automatic
# maintenance (custom daily cronjobs, replication, and similar tasks).
#
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

(NOTE THAT I HAVE NOT CONFIGURED the postgresql it's password. how can I configure it?)

However when I am accessing the said server on my machine this error occurs

```
The server doesn't accept connections: the connection library reports 
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "<ip.address>" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Comment: You have installed postgresql, you have not actually started it. Doing `sudo -i -u postgres` doesn't access the database, it just starts a shell with the postgres user instead of your own user.

Comment: @JennyD how do you start postgresql?

Comment: Start reading at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/tutorial-start.html

Comment: This question is being voted for closure because the author does not show a level of technical understanding or appropriate due diligence in researching the topic that the community judges as being a minimum barrier to participate.